# D'où vient le R uvulaire du français ?

Tags: histoire, phonétique

Dans toutes les langues romanes, à l'exception du français, /R/ est prononcé roulé et alvéolaire [r] alors qu'il est fricatif et uvulaire [ʁ] en français standard. D'où vient cette particularité ? De quand ce changement date-t-il ?

---

In every romance language, except French, the phoneme /R/ is an alveolar trill [r], while in French it is an uvular fricative [ʁ]. Whence comes this singularity, and when did the change happen?

Comment: Where else other than in French is this uvular r used ?

Comment: peut-il y avoir une influence du breton qui ne roule pas les r?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

D'après [la thèse sur l'évolution du R en français](https://summit.sfu.ca/system/files/iritems1/7108/b18055618.pdf) de [Meike Wernicke-Heinrichs](http://www.mwernicke.ca/index.html),

> *The fricative pronunciation of **r** is said to have originated in popular speech [...] in the southern regions of France, and the moved across central France until finally reaching Paris in the sixteen century.*
> (pp 47-48)

Cette prononciation viendrait donc du sud de la France, où (voir document pour plus de détails), des assimilations fréquentes entre `[r]` et `[z]` se seraient produites, l'origine de ce phénomène étant encore discutée, certains penchant, entre autres, pour un passage par `[ð]` et `[r↘]`.

[Une carte trouvée sur Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Uvular_rhotics_in_Europe.png), sans pour autant contredire cette étude, donne une aire de répartition du /R/ uvulaire au choix centrée sur le Rhin ou avec plusieurs foyers de diffusion en Scandinavie, en Allemagne et en France. Cette prononciation a donc aussi pu être influencée par les langues germaniques.

[image: Répartition du /R/ uvulaire en Europe]

---

<sub>**Note** : le lien direct vers le document semble peu fiable, en cas de péremption, il devrait néanmoins être disponible sur [le site de l'université Simon Frasier](https://summit.sfu.ca/item/7108).</sub>

Comment: C'est étrange parce que dans la moitié sud de la France la langue principale était l'occitan où le r est roulé.

Comment: En regardant de plus près l’article et le passage cité, le progrès du sud vers le nord n’est pas celui du r guttural, mais seulement de l’assibilation, la confusion avec z. Et même cette hypothèse, soutenue par deux auteurs cités (Thurot, 1881-83. p.273; Giauque. 1975, p.410) est explicitement contredite par trois autres (Cledat. 1927. p.85, Meyer 1875. p. 194, Martinet 1962. pp.200-201) .

Comment: L’assibilation a été suivie par un restauration du r `due to the influence of grammarians and the written language … Another commonly cited factor, linguistic in this case, is the guttural pronunciation of r, which was rapidly gaining popularity at that time.` (Ce qui envoie encore à des causes socio-culturelles.) En plus, la partie citée est seulement préliminaire au sein de l’article, qui  n’est pas vraiment concerné par la question « D'où vient le R uvulaire du français ? », mais par son évolution comme preuve de sa « stabilité flexible » (flexible stability, p.105).

Answer (score 12):

Il y a un [article Wikipédia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_phon%C3%A8me_/r/_en_fran%C3%A7ais) qui apporte un début de réponse :

> Le R roulé (consonne roulée alvéolaire voisée), utilisé en latin [r], s’est conservé en français (ancien français et moyen français) jusqu’au XVII<sup>e</sup> siècle dans les centres urbains, et jusqu’au XVIII<sup>e</sup> siècle en général avant d’être remplacé par le R grasseyé (consonne roulée uvulaire voisée).
>
> Selon Rousselot, « l’r grasseyé dérive de l’r dentale par un abaissement, qui a été progressif, de la pointe de la langue derrière les dents inférieures, avec une élévation compensatoire du dos de la langue » ; et « l’évolution qui a donné l’r parisienne a commencé par la confusion de cette consonne avec z ».

Answer (score 2):

Voila un [bon article](http://monsu.desiderio.free.fr/curiosites/r-phono.html) sur ce sujet.

> **Le r uvulaire ou grasseyé**
>
> Le [r] apical cède progressivement la place à la fin du XVIIe s. à un [ʁ] uvulaire (du latin uvula, luette) : les locuteurs cherchent dans la luette à produire les battements qu'ils ne peuvent plus obtenir avec la pointe de la langue. La difficulté à obtenir ces battements sera illustrée ensuite par les changements de prononciation cités, elle commence dès le XIIIe s., notamment en finale. Le r uvulaire lui est signalé dès 1689 dans l'usage de la cour où l'on ne prononce plus l'r « jusqu'à écorcher les oreilles ».

Comment: Merci de ne pas inclure seulement un lien, mais aussi un résumé qui répond à la question.