# Étymologie de « grasseyer » : le [ʁ] est gras ?

Tags: prononciation, étymologie

[Ce fil](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/340/1995) m'a introduit à ce verbe. Comment est-ce que le [ʁ] se pense ou s'estime gras ?

> [[Wiktionnaire :]](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/grasseyer) Dérivé de gras avec le suffixe -eyer (→ voir -oyer).

Comment: Le son visé par *[grasseyer](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phon%C3%A8me_/r/_en_fran%C3%A7ais)* est plutôt [ʀ], que [ʁ].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gras indique ici que le r est prononcé en faisant vibrer la langue et la luette.

Cette vibration est associée à l'altération de la prononciation due à une langue épaisse, au sens propre ou au sens figuré. On retrouve peut-être ce même « gras » dans l'expression « toux grasse » par opposition à « toux sèche ».

Voir par exemple cette définition du dictionnaire de la langue française de Jean-Charles Laveaux (1828):

[image]